# array_unique not working in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, array-unique

I have got a table in my MySql database:

```
  pageid   | text
-----------+----------
    1      | test
-----------+----------
    2      | example
-----------+----------
    3      | another
-----------+----------
    1      | example1
```

and this PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT pageid FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row['pageid'];
  $id1 = array($id);
  $id2 = array_unique($id1);
  foreach ($id2 as $value)
    {
    echo $value . "<br>";
    }
  }
```

But it returns:

```
1
2
3
1
```

I would like to make the `pageid`s unique. So I would like to echo out the number `1`, once. Like this:

```
1
2
3
```

So what am I doing wrong? How could I achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance...

[I know that this code doesn't make much sense, but this is just a demo for this question and I have a much more complicated code :) ]

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that you can use group by in mysql, but just incase, here is your heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the real answer in this situation is to select distinct records to begin with:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT pageid FROM test";
```

But as to why your code doesn't work...

You are declaring `$id1` as an array, but not appending to it. Instead you're just creating a 1 element array each time. Instead, append all results then call `array_unique()`

```
$query = "SELECT pageid FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Declare array first
$id1 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row['pageid'];
  // Append to the array...
  $id1[] = $id;
  }

// Call array_unique() outside the loop:
$id2 = array_unique($id1);
foreach ($id2 as $value)
{
  echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your `SELECT` by doing something like `SELECT DISTINCT pageid FROM test` or by using `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT pageid FROM test WHERE 1 GROUP BY pageid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct keyword in your sql query.That will return you the unique vaues of Page